# HTML form returns NULL fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a basic form with several fields that i want to validate before submitting the code. However when i pass the form data to the js it says that the fields are null. Any help please? Im new at JS so please be patient with me. 
The relevant form. Theres a button to toggle the forms display but i dont think that has any effect on this.

```
<div id = "new_bk" style="display: none;">
    <form id = "New_Book" onsubmit = "javscript: return(FormValidate());">
        Book Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="book_name">

        <br>
        Author name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="author_name">

        <br>
        ISBN:<br>
        <input type="text" name="ISBN">

        <br>
        Release Date:<br>
        <input type="text" name="release_date">

        <br>
        Price:<br>
        <input type="text" name="price">

        <br>
        Stock:<br>
        <input type="text" name="stock">

        <br>
        Sold:<br>
        <input type="text" name="sold">

        <br>
        Restock amount:<br>
        <input type="text" name="restock">

        <br>
        Rating:<br>
        <input type="text" name="rating">

        <br>
        Reviews:<br>
        <input type="text" name="reviews">

        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

and the js

```
function FormValidate(){
    // if(document.getElementById("book_name").value.length>0){
    //     alert("ok");
    // }else{
    //     alert("not ok");
    // }
    alert("Name is: "  + document.getElementById('book_name').value);
    if(document.New_Book.book_name.value == ""){
        alert("sdkg");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However this does not trigger the alert box. and if i switch it to

```
alert(document.getElementById('book_name'));
```

it gives me a null.

Any and all help would be much appreciated. Oh and in case this matters. The js is in an external file that is referenced at the end of the body tag of the html file.

**UPDATE**

the form sends the data correctly now. but now something odd happens.

```
alert("1");

if(document.New_Book.book_name.value == ''){
    alert("Input book name please");
    return false;
}

alert("2");
```

this code segment will only trigger alert("1") then end. Neither the fail scenario alert nor alert("2") are triggered. any ideas why?

Comment: I don't think you can refer to form Id directly... I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: @BrianMains sorry. that was just a habit from my days of java :( god i feel so embarassed. asking such stupid questions. thanks again for clearing it up for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this code:

```
alert(document.getElementById('book_name'));
```

Notice the textbox has no id attribute that you are trying to traget.

```
<input type="text" name="book_name">
```

Change to add an ID attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="book_name" name="book_name">
```

and it will work.

Comment: oh my god. i feel like such a fool. how did i not see that? Thank you so much! Ill accept this as the answer asap.

Comment: It happens to everyone . Thanks

Comment: a little help please?

Comment: Why are you using new_book? I would recommend against and use document.getElememtById('book_name').value

Answer (score 1):

You have the form "name" listed there - that's better for PHP. If you're pulling it by the id you need to specify id="[your value here]" to get it to work. Add an additional field to your tags

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an element by its `ID`, but you do not have any IDs set to your elements, so you need to add

```
<input type="text" name="book_name" id="book_name">
```

However, I think more clever would be to select all inputs at once and then loop through them for validation. You can do that with querySelectorAll for example:

```
var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('form > input');
for (var i = 0; i<allInputs.length;i++) {
    if (allInputs[i].value == ''){ 
        alert(allInputs[i].getAttribute('name') + ' is not filled');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to `document.getElementByName('book_name')` or if you want to select by ID html should look like this `<input type="text" id="book_name">`

Retrieving element by name attribute: `document.getElementByName('book_name')`
Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

Retrieving element by id attribute: `document.getElementById('book_name')`
Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp